# How to add play and stop different button song in android

Tags: android

I am making an application for Android and I have made buttons to play and pause. My play button and pause one are set up, so when I click the play or pause button and first it will run, but in button two it doesn't work.The code is given below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cdp.keroncong;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mplayer;

    public void playAudio(View view) {

        mplayer.start();

    }

    public void pauseAudio(View view) {

        mplayer.stop();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Button1);
       //mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Button1);


       }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank's before

Comment: i don't think i properly understand your question, do you mean you have four buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this Code, it will help you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer Song;
    int pause;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }

    public void play(View view){

        if(Song == null){
        Song = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.music);
        Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }

        else if(!Song.isPlaying()){
            Song.seekTo(pause);
            Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     }
   }
    public void pause(View view){
        if(Song!= null){
        Song.pause();
        pause = Song.getCurrentPosition();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }
    public void stop(View view){

        Song.stop();
        Song = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


xml.file

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Play"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="play" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/pause"
        android:onClick="pause" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:onClick="stop" />
```

> Let me know if it will help you

Comment: How to get different content with different button click? such as playButton 2, playButton 3, ...., or with different buttons and music.. thank's

Answer (score 0):

This my activity_main.xml

```
**activity_main.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="215dp"
        android:onClick="playAudio" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playButton"
        android:onClick="pauseAudio"
        android:text="Pause"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="88dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/banana"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orange"
        android:onClick="playAudio"
        android:text="Play"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orange"
        android:onClick="pauseAudio"
        android:text="Pause"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="88dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: there are two buttons with the same id "@+id/pauseButton"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, place it in your OnCreate method right after this  `mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Button1);`

```
//      Play song
    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPlayer.start(); 
        }
    });
    //      Pause song
    Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    });
```

i modified your XML to look like this although I can't fully correct it until I see the whole thing

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orange"
        android:text="Play"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orange"
        android:text="Pause"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="88dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```